# 'Empathetic,' but relating to one's environment/surroundings instead of to people

Tags: single-word-requests

If to be "empathetic" is to have a strong understanding of people and their thoughts and emotions, what would be the equivalent adjective for one with a strong understanding of their environment, the events and interactions within it, and their consequences? "Intuition" comes to mind and speaks of the predictive angle, but is broader than I'd like, as it could be considered an umbrella term under which *empathy* falls. I'm looking for a word that also falls under that umbrella but is focused on environmental intuition.

*In tune* and s*ynchronized with X* get closer, but a one-word counterpart of *empathy* would be ideal.

Comment: You want a single word, and I don't have one, but I have heard two phrases:  "one with X", where X is usually "nature", but can be, for example, "the Sierra" or "the rainforest".  Another phrase  is "of X", as in "I am of the ice", used in a book by a woman who overwintered at South Pole.   Again, X could be "the rainforest" or "the tundra" or "the Sierra", etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"perspicacious"(adj)/"perspicacity"(n)

I first thought of "perceptive", as it means you know what's around you, but it doesn't necessarily capture the meaning of understanding of your environment. For example you may be very perceptive of the electrical wire in proximity to the pool of water, yet not be conscious its potential hazard.

So instead I think "perspicacious" is fitting. In my opinion it has meanings both of perceptiveness and understanding. If we check the dictionary definitions that's indeed what sort of meanings we get, with common themes of "discernment" and "understanding":

> adj
>   1. acutely perceptive or discerning
>  [Collins English Dictionary](http://1.%20acutely%20perceptive%20or%20discerning)
>
> adj.
>  Having or showing penetrating mental discernment;
>   clear-sighted
>  [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/perspicacious)
>
> of acute mental vision or discernment
>  [Merriam-Webster
>   Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perspicacious)
>
> Having a ready insight into and understanding of things.
>  [Oxford
>   Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/perspicacious)

"Discerning" may be as good, but for me at least I see/hear in "perspicacious" other familiar words, ie., perspective/perceptive/perception.

Though the etymology shouldn't be important, I give it here anyway.

> perspicacious
>   [C17: from Latin perspicax, from perspicere to look at closely; see
>   perspective] 
> [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/perspicacious)

It may sound a bit highfalutin, but it's not terribly uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

"Atuned," "Aware" or "cognizant" I think may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**rapport** [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/rapport)

> a sympathetic relationship or understanding; a close relationship

As in:

> In close **rapport** with X.